# How do I remove "curriculum vitae" text from heading of \documentclass{tccv}?

Tags: titles, cv

I'm working with the Two Column CV template from https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv/

The script begins with:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

I don't want it to say Curriculum Vitae at the top (as it current does), but I don't see where I can remove that text to either have it say "Resume" or simply have no text at all in the heading.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the desired change (an original line commented, then changed):

```
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    {\usekomafont{part} #1} \medskip\\
    %{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Curriculum vitae}
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Resume}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}]}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.cls` has this redefinition of `\part`:

```
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
        \vskip-\lastskip%
        {\usekomafont{part} #1} \medskip\\
        {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Curriculum vitae}
        \bigskip
    \end{center}]}
```

As you can see, the phrase is hard-wired into the definition.  You could simply remove it:

```
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
        \vskip-\lastskip%
        {\usekomafont{part} #1} \par
        \bigskip
    \end{center}]}
```

I'm not sure what kind of vertical spacing you're hoping to get after your name, however.

Answer (score 0):

go to the .cls file. At line 75 remove second argument for \renewcommand

Comment: This is what both other answers say. Also, what you say is the "second argument" is actually just a line of text.

Comment: Editing the `.cls` file is a very bad way to do this. If you must, you'd want to rename a copy of the file and class. But the less invasive approaches already suggested would be preferable here.